# runOnUiThread not updating listview

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-runonuithread

I think ive looked at almost all threads wont seem  to work.
Ive got a chat and im trying to update the list view every second im doing it on another thread however, im using `runOnUiThread` though it still wont update im logging the return and it seems there is a return every second with the correct data.
The code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ........

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.message_array);

    returnFunc = "messages";

    messages();
    send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendMessage);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            returnFunc = "btnSend";
            message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
            message_input = message.getText().toString();
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean test = true;

            while (test) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                messages();

            }



        }
    }).start();


}



 public static Handler handler = new Handler();
public void messageLoop(){
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    messages();
                    handler.postDelayed(this,1000);

                }
            });
        }
    },1000);
}
```

the messages function which gets the data fine

```
public void messages() {
    String urlParameters = String.format("%s", "chatid="+tempVars.chatID+"&token="+tempVars.token);
    new AsyncHttpPost(this).execute("http://mylink.com/appAccess.php?action=messages&", urlParameters);

}



public void getMessages(String content){
    myList = new ArrayList<Messages>();

    int index = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - lv.getPaddingTop());


    try{
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(content);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            boolean mine;
            if(jsonobject.getString("isMine").equals("true")){
                mine = true;
            }else{
                mine = false;
            }

            myList.add(new Messages(jsonobject.getString("message"),jsonobject.getString("timestamp"),jsonobject.getString("name"),mine,jsonobject.getString("id")));
        }

    }catch (Throwable tx){

    }

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3)
        {
            Messages CurrentMessage = myList.get(position);
            tempVars.messageID = CurrentMessage.getID();
            //startActivity(new Intent("PersonalChat"));
        }
    });

    if(arrayAdapter == null){
        arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myList);
    }
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.message_array);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if(firstView == 0){
        firstView = 1;
        lv.setSelection(arrayAdapter.getCount() - 1);
    }else{
        lv.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
    }

}
```

class CustomAdapter

```
   public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Messages>{
    Messages currentMessage;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList<Messages> messages){
        super(context,R.layout.received_message, messages);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;

        currentMessage = myList.get(position);
        setTitle(currentMessage.getName());


        if(currentMessage.isMine()){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sent_message,parent, false);

            TextView message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            message.setText(currentMessage.getMessage());

            TextView timestamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            timestamp.setText(currentMessage.getTimestamp());
        }else{
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.received_message,parent, false);

            TextView message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            message.setText(currentMessage.getMessage());

            TextView timestamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            timestamp.setText(currentMessage.getTimestamp());
        }

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

**More info**

When i call the message function originally in onCreate it works fine

Comment: Initialize the CustomAdapter only once and notify it only when any item is added or removed from the list.

Comment: Drv its right, and you also are adding an empty adapter in your lv

Comment: @Drv thanks will try now and update you

Comment: @LucasPaolillo oh but the adapter is set?

Comment: @Drv seems to have no change ?

Comment: @Drv i added the folllowing 

if(arrayAdapter == null){
            arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        }

Comment: You need to pass some parameters of list you want to set in adapter.For ex: arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(YOURLIST); And also u must have CustomAdapter class.

Comment: @Drv my class doesnt take parameters added thhe code above

Comment: Add your complete code.

Comment: @Drv added everything in CustomAdapter class that ok?

Comment: Please refer this link and try to correct your adapter class first. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: @Drv okay although it does update the listview when its not called in the separate thread

Comment: @Drv updated as it is in the github link no change

Comment: You need to post all your code with all your files ,otherwise I can't help.

Comment: @Drv it seem Asynctask does the trick how would i go about calling it every second in same thread

Comment: @Drv still didnt work updated thread with all my code

Comment: @JoshMitch Check my answer if it helps.

Comment: @Drv thanks but still the same

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean test = true;

             while (test) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }mymessage();

            }



        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: this is not returning data every second

Comment: great ill test now

Answer (score 0):

Replace your getMessages() method with below code:

```
public void getMessages(String content){
myList = new ArrayList<Messages>();

int index = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - lv.getPaddingTop());


try{
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(content);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        boolean mine;
        if(jsonobject.getString("isMine").equals("true")){
            mine = true;
        }else{
            mine = false;
        }

        myList.add(new Messages(jsonobject.getString("message"),jsonobject.getString("timestamp"),jsonobject.getString("name"),mine,jsonobject.getString("id")));
    }

    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}catch (Throwable tx){

}

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3)
    {
        Messages CurrentMessage = myList.get(position);
        tempVars.messageID = CurrentMessage.getID();
        //startActivity(new Intent("PersonalChat"));
    }
});

if(arrayAdapter == null){
    arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myList);
}
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.message_array);
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


if(firstView == 0){
    firstView = 1;
    lv.setSelection(arrayAdapter.getCount() - 1);
}else{
    lv.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
}

}
```

Comment: do u have anything i can contact you on directly

Comment: however final Handler handler = new Handler()
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        chas();
        handler.postDelayed( this, 1000 );
    }
}, 1000 );

works on my get recent chats it updates lv fine its basically the same code